# Subject -verb agreement with appositive clauses

Tags: verb-agreement

When I add an appositive clause explaining subject that is different in term of singular/plural , how to choose verb agreement with the subject. Should I use " these chemical reactions" or " that is the greenhouse effect" as a subject  or should I avoid all along by not adding appositive clause?

> Some greenhouse gases such as carbon-monoxide or water vapor are
>   natural gases which exist in the atmosphere already. Nevertheless, when
>   we produce too much of the greenhouse gases, they trap the solar heat rays and
>   prevent them from escaping from the Earth's atmosphere and surface.
>   These chemical reactions, that is the greenhouse effect, 
>   **results/ result** in global warming.

Does the fact that *these* refers to the post-positioned *the greenhouse effect* affect the choice of tense?

Comment: Plural "result" is required since the expression _that is the greenhouse effect_ is supplemental, an interpolation, as are most clauses introduced by _that is_ (called an 'indicator'), and hence does not make the subject NP singular. Incidentally, the supplement is not an appositive; it's just an ascriptive NP supplement. It doesn't qualify as apposition because the supplement cannot be substituted for the whole construction in such a way as to yield an entailment of the original.

Comment: @Mrt, I'm going to edit your quoted statement to try and fix some distracting errors in order to concentrate on your question. I think there is an interesting issue buried in here. You can roll the edit back if you don't like what I did.